# Plain UDP shows up as STUN in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, udp

I am sending 4 bytes of data over UDP upon request from another program. Sometimes the frame's protocol is identified as STUN in Wireshark, but I have no clue why.

A ruby prototype of the communication looks like this(simpled down as much as possible for clarity)

The requesting code:

```
require 'Socket'

sock = UDPSocket.new

loop do
  sock.send "req", 0, "127.0.0.1", 40004
  x = sock.recvfrom 4
  dataLength = x[0].unpack('L')[0]
  received = 0
  sleep 2
end
```

The answering code:

```
require 'Socket'

sock = UDPSocket.new
sock.bind "127.0.0.1", 40004

loop do
  x = sock.recvfrom 3
  if x[0] == 'req'
    sock.send [(Random.rand 10000..300000)].pack('L'), 0, "127.0.0.1", x[1][1]
  end
end
```

When analizing this communication in Wireshark, it shows that the frames sent by

```
sock.send [(Random.rand 10000..300000)].pack('L'), 0, "127.0.0.1", x[1][2]
```

are sometimes identified as plain UDP, sometimes as STUN. I noticed that 2 most significant bytes of the STUN frames I checked have values of 0x00, bet some plain UDP frames also have 2 most significant bytes with value of 0x00.

Image of a STUN frame:
[image: STUN frame]

Image of a plain UDP frame: [image: UDP frame]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just coincidence. You are generating a random payload, and sometimes the random bytes generated will have the header structure of a STUN packet.